# How to run PL/SQL program in Oracle10g for Linux

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

```
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to PL/SQL');
END;
/
```

I have this code in `sample.sql` file.
How to run `sample.sql`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run it using [SQL*Plus](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/toc.htm) (using your `username`/`password` and the name of your instance):

```
sqlplus username/password@instance @ sample.sql
```

Another way would be to download free [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) from Oracle, open and execute the file there.

---

Note that the text will not be displayed per default, you need to [enable the output](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/serveroutput.html) before.

Put the following line into your file as first line:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

Comment: It's better to put the connect string in the sql script, or to get the password through a environment variable; a command like the one Peter Lang showed reveals the password to anyone on the host with the `ps` command.